# volatile variable is not giving expected output

Tags: java, multithreading, static, threadpool, thread-synchronization

I read that volatile variable copy will shared by all the threads and once completion of the execution, the update value will get by every thread,But in the following program using thread pool not giving the output which I expected, can any one tell me the reason?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class Task implements Runnable{
    volatile int v1=10;

    private String name;

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public  synchronized void  run() {
        v1=v1+10;
        System.out.println(name +"is entered "+v1);

    }

}
public class ThreadPoolTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r1 = new Task("Thread 1"); 
        Runnable r2 = new Task("Thread 2"); 
        Runnable r3 = new Task("Thread 3"); 

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        executor.execute(r1);
        executor.execute(r2);
        executor.execute(r3);

        executor.shutdown();  
    }
}

outPut:

Thread 1is entered 20
Thread 2is entered 20
Thread 3is entered 20

but if we change from volatile to static its giving below output:

Thread 1is entered 20
Thread 3is entered 30
Thread 2is entered 40
```

Comment: Which is totally making sense because you create 3 instances of Task class and its instance has its own v1 variable. So when you make ot static,all tasks share the same variable. Thats why it goes 20 30 40.

Comment: Don't `change from volatile to static`, instead ADD the static while retaining the volatile (ie. change from "volatile" to "static volatile")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observed result is correct as you are creating three separate `Task` instances who are having their own copy of the `name` variable.

So although they are `volatile` the values are not updated by other threads the thread executing the particular instance is the one which is updating the `v1` field.

If the `v1` is made static then it becomes a `class` member so obviously the threads will update the same copy of the variable `v1`.

Instead of using `synchronized` on the `run` method, we can use the `AtomicInteger` to safely update and fetch the value.

```
class Task implements Runnable{
    private final AtomicInteger v1 = new AtomicInteger(10);

    private String name;

    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + v1.addAndGet(10));
    }

}
public class ThreadPoolTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r1 = new Task();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executor.execute(r1);
        executor.execute(r1);
        executor.execute(r1);
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `v1` is an instance variable and each task has its own.

So in the example you incremented `v1` of different instances. `static` also is not reliable since you are sinchronizing on the instance of a `Task` so it still has a race condition (e.g. each thread may read `v1`'s value to be 10 even in case of `static volatile`)

Probably you need `AtomicInteger`

Comment: Yes, much better to pass in an `AtomicInteger` to the Runnables' constructors. Avoid global/static variables.

Answer (score 1):

To be short, volatile or Atomic Variables are the solutions to solve the inconsistency(**Memory Consistency Errors**) when  two or more threads try to access the **same resource(can be static/non-static)** simultaneously.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

In your case, **you are not sharing your task with more than one Threads.** so no need of using volatile keyword or Atomic variables. if you want to share your variable with more than one thread, then you can use Atomic variables over volatile.

then what happens, when you add static keyword to a variable?

static variables are available to all objects of that class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html